# How to set up clang format to not trim empty lines at the end of C++ files?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm using VS Code for C++ and clang format for formatting. I like to leave several empty lines at the end of every code file, but clang format trims them. My .clang-format file is:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
Language: Cpp
IndentWidth: 4
AccessModifierOffset: -4
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
PointerAlignment: Left
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 10
AlignTrailingComments: true
```

If I set `BasedOnStyle: none` or `BasedOnStyle: InheritParentConfig`  the problem disappears but formatting doesn't work at all. As the problem definitely is in my preset of .clang-format how can I correct it to get desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since clang-format 17: [**KeepEmptyLinesAtEOF** (`Boolean`)](https://intel.github.io/llvm-docs/clang/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#keepemptylinesateof)

> Keep empty lines (up to `MaxEmptyLinesToKeep`) at end of file.